# What is the feedback mechanism behind this motor?

Tags: dc-motor

I would like to play around with this servo motor but I'm not sure what the feedback mechanism on it is or what the interface is.

The mechanism has 3 wires leading to it (yellow, orange, brown). It consists of a hard black disc (I think the disc is metal or possibly a ceramic?), a PCB behind it that has a square wave pattern around the circumference of the board, and on the board itself there are a couple resistors, ceramic capacitors and a single 8 pin IC (I can't see what is on the IC, I don't want to take the mechanism apart).

The motor came from an old photocopier.

My best guess is that it might be a magnetic resolver but I've never had any experience with them.

So the question is: What is the mechanism in the picture and how would I go about interfacing it (ie, if it was an encoder, I'd do quadrature decoding ect).

[image: motor]

Comment: Three wires for just the sensor, or for the sensor and motor?

Comment: He stated that the feedback mechanism has three wires!

Comment: Total of five wires. 2 got the motor and 3 for the sensor.

Comment: any evidence of permanent magnets in that rotor?

Comment: Actually no, there wasn't any (tested it with a small piece of steel but I didn't test it against a magnet for fear of damaging it with strong neodymium magnets). I also only tested the outside face, not the one facing the PCB.

Comment: tried to read the markings off that end plate. could you post that info?

Comment: @JustJeff: Sure thing:(1st line) DC-5216-053 (2nd line) DC24V 1.65A 1200r.p.m. (3rd line) 12Gq 80011 (4th line) 54031 (5th line) SHINANO KENSHI CO.,LTD. MADE IN JAPAN. I tried googling the model number and looking it up on the manufacturer website but I found nothing.

Comment: @Faken - yeah, I see what you mean. It's probably one of their 'custom assemblies'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With just three wires, I don't see how it can supply a quadrature output. For that, a supply for the IC, ground, and two wires for the quadrature outputs would be required. It's probably just a tacho.

Comment: Any idea what kind of interface it would be? Analog voltage? Sine waves?

Comment: @Faken - probably one line is a ground, another is excitation (might be DC, might be AC), and the 3rd line is some kind of sense signal, that will just give you speed.

Comment: Tachometers are analog voltage proportional to the rotational speed of the shaft.

Answer (score 1):

In fact that is a single channel encoder. Maybe optical or magnetic (hall sensored). 3 wires encoders are always: 5vdc input, gnd input and pulse output.-

Answer (score 1):

The output is only a speed feedback.

Magnetic pickup on the PCB tracks, with the magnetic disk mounted on the shaft.

Some type of comparator circuit with the [TA75393P](https://www.ersinelektronik.com/class/INNOVAEditor/assets/Datasheets/TA75393P.pdf) dual comparator.

[image: photo of PCB track side]

[image: photo of PCB component side]